# What does besides mean?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, vocabulary, antonyms

besides has two definitions in the dictionary

one is apart from (except)

and second is in addition to

I was wondering aren't these two antonyms??

Answer (score 1):

1. *Apart from* when in the negative. *There's no one here besides Bill and me.*
2. *In addition to* when in the affirmative. *Besides a mother he has a sister to support.*

Comment: lol and someone told me besides is an auto antonym

Answer (score 0):

The form "besides ... only" also invokes the "apart from" meaning.

> Besides battleships, only aircraft carriers are considered "capital ships".

In fact, in this case "besides" means **both** apart from **and** in addition to.